# Cannot access management pages for GCloud Services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-memorystore

[image]

I think there's an issue accessing the management pages for GCloud Services such as Serverless VPC Access and Memorystore. I have enabled billing since project inception and have been running other billing required services, such as Cloud Natural language API.

Please what could be the problem? And Google Cloud support reps seem not to understand the issue either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, those UI are not showing in your console? If so, there are some considerations and questions you might want to answer yourself:

- Is this happening only to me?
- Is this happening only to my user?
- Is this happening only to my computer?

The issue you are facing could be due to:

- Your web browser
- Some kind of firewall rules you have in your network
- Any proxies you use.

You can try:

1. Delete cookies and cache from your web browser.
2. Try from an incognito window.
3. Another user.
4. Another computer from an incognito window
5. Another computer in different network.

You can also share some screenshots about the error you are facing. Sometimes, when a UI can not be shown properly, the UI responds with a Tracking number.

Comment: Thanks @joss baron. I have tried all you've suggested but couldn't make it past the screen (which I have now added to the question). Notice the API & Services above the Serverless VPC Access API. It's not supposed to be there. And there's supposed to be an option to create a connector

Comment: It is interesting. It sounds like if it is not recognized that your API is enabled. Could you please confirm if you are trying this path?: Navigation Menu / VPC Network / Serverless VPC access? I have created a quick Project and the first time I am requested to enable the API, once it is enabled I can see the Serverless VPC acces and it allows me to create a connector. Maybe are you trying Navigation Menu / APIs&Services / Dashboard / and selecting Serverless VPC Access API (which would not be the proper path to create a connector)?

Comment: You can also try in the Search bar and type: Serverless VPC Access, be sure to pick the option Serverless VPC Access.

Comment: Yes, @joss baron. I tried that too but was not able to get to the connector or memorystore management pages.

Comment: To solve the problem, I disabled the API using the console (web interface) and reenabled it using gcloud cli, after which am able to access the management pages.

Thanks so much for your help